# Can you run KSQL from a remote host?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I have confluent-ksql-server running on one of the nodes of my cluster .
Can we make the ksql to be connected by a specific host/machine outside the kafka cluster ?

PS- this is to provide ksql access to developers

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can.  KSQL supports Client-Server architecture.  It has ksql server which runs on one machine and client can be independently run on another machine.

[image]

When you start the ksql-server on your cluster nodes, you need to configure the listeners in ksql-server.properties.  Listeners should be exposed as 0.0.0.0: in order to make it accessible from other machine.

From your local machines, you can access via ksql-cli in following way:

```
 ./bin/ksql-cli remote http://<kafka Node Listern IP>:8080
```

You can read more about KSQL Client Server setup here : https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply Nishu! 
Can we expose the listener to  specific IP addresses ? With 0.0.0.0 , anyone on the same network can invoke ksql .

Comment: Yes, you can configure the KSQL server to listen only on a specific IP address.